# how to add presto SQLalchemy URI to be connected in airbnb data visualization tool superset

Tags: sqlalchemy, uri, visualization, presto, apache-superset

i have both presto and superset setup.

presto is working well, can be accessed by command:

```
. /app/hadoop/setjdk8.sh;bin/presto-cli --server http://myserver:8070 --catalog hive --schema default
```

And tested ok with a sql query select count(*) on a hive table.

superset is also setup on same server, and web UI is OK to access. but always fail to connect to presto when trying to do "Add Database" action to presto. The SQLAlchemy URI is input as:

```
presto://myserver:8070/default
```

Same error always pops out when "Test Connection" button is clicked.

As to URI, after presto://, hostname, localhost, 127.0.0.1, ip all are tried, all end into 502 popout.

Here is the error pic,
[image: 502 error, can't connect to presto in superset]

Answer (score 1):

You have the right URL, you just need to pass the schema as a query parameter and maybe drop the port number like this:

```
presto://myserver/?schema=default
```

Please make sure that your presto server is actually listening on port 8070 as its default is 8080 and superset usually connects fine without adding the port number.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter --server http://myserver:8070 is kind of weird ... have you tried just --server myserver:8070 ???

Answer (score 0):

`presto://example.com:8080/system` This worked for me with presto 316 version . `system` is catalog name